# What is the entry point for each request to our rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance, rack

Findings: Entry point of each rack application is `config.ru`

```
require_relative 'config/environment'

run Rails.application
```

The `Rails.application` call returns an instance of your application class. For each request do rails create a new app instance?

If so, all request get new app instance? but it's not possible because each of my app instances will take DB connections as mentioned in `database.yml`. I think I am missing some part.

Comment: This article might answer your question: [Examining The Internals Of The Rails Request/Response Cycle](https://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/examining-internals-of-rails-request-response-cycle/)

Comment: in this blog it's "Rack apps define their entry point in the config.ru file, and Rails is no different." as I mentioned Rails.application call returns an instance of your application class so is it that my all request get new app instance? but it's not possible because each of my app instance will take connections as per mentioned in database.yml
I think I am missing some part.

Comment: The article says "the `Rails.application` call returns _an_ instance of your application class". It doesn't say it returns a _new_ instance. Once an instance returned from a request it will be re-use to respond to another request.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @spickermann got that part in Rails module application method is memoized.